# r annotate values above geometric bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this sample data.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2)),
  y = c(.1, .3, .2, .1),
  grp = c("a", "b", "a", "b")
)
```

Now I create the graph using `ggplot`, and annotate it using `geom_text()`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = grp, label = y)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
      geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

How do I specify that all the text values align perfectly horizontal at the top of the graph window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `aes(y=...)` in `geom_text`. So, for the numbers at the top of the graph window you'll have

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = grp, label = y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(y=Inf), position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

And you may want to chuck in a `+ ylim(0, 4)` to expand the plot area.

---

To match the edited question:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = grp, label = y)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) +
    geom_text(aes(y=0.9), position = position_dodge(0.9))  ## can specify any y=.. value
```

Comment: Perfect! Although infinity is not desired since it misses half of the symbols, I figured from your information that I could simply use y=1. Thanks!

Comment: @MvZB Yes, set `y=anynumber` and it works just the same :)